# Pass value to factory angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to pass article id from url to factory but I can't get the value from `$routeChangeSuccess` callback.

```
myApp.controller('editCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, getArticleById, $filter, $route, $routeParams) {

    var article_id = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        return $routeParams.id;
    });   

    getArticleById.get(article_id).then(function(data) {
        $scope.articles = data;
    });
});

myApp.factory('getArticleById', function($q, $http) {
    return {
        get: function(article_id) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/api/admin/article/edit/'+ article_id).success(function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }).error(function(result) {
                deferred.reject(result);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

**$routeProvider**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','ui.utils','ngSanitize','ui.tinymce'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        //configure the routing rules here
        $routeProvider.when('/admin/article/edit/:id', {
            controller: 'editCtrl'
        });

        //routing DOESN'T work without html5Mode
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
);
```

Comment: what values are you getting in your `$routeChangeSuccess` function? Can you log some stuff out? That function also has three params `function(event, next, current)`

Comment: That's the issue in $routeChangeSuccess I am getting right article id value but when I am trying pass it to article_id var it is not possible  it's undefined

Comment: no template declarations in your $routeProvider? $routeParams.id should not be null when the controller is invoked. Something is amiss in the $routeProvider configuration. Please post the full configuration.

Comment: No template - bad practice? I am using laravel and views. Thi is full conig

Comment: Okay. Is this all your routes in you app? From where do you navigate to the URL for this controller? What is the default URL? If the routing is configured properly, the $routeParams service injected in your controller will provide you with the URL params. Thats the expected behavour. I suggest fix the routing than implement a hack in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a var named article_id in your controller, simply use the $routeParams.id to pass the value to factory.

```
  getArticleById.get($routeParams.id).then(function(data) {
            $scope.articles = data;
        });
```

Comment: $routeParams.id is null it has a value only in $routeChangeSuccess callback function but I have no idea how to get this value

Comment: please post your $routeProvider config. If you want to invoke the factory method right when route change happens, you can perhaps make the factory call inside the $routeChangeSuccess callback itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can just update the articles in the `$routeChangeSuccess` callback.

```
myApp.controller('editCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, getArticleById, $filter, $route, $routeParams) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        getArticleById.get($routeParams.id).then(function(data) {
            $scope.articles = data;
        });
    });   
});
```

This might cause problems when there is multiple route changes in quick successions. In which case you would need to do some more work.